# How make this switch better?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I got a problem with repetition in my JavaScript code. I have got a multiple switch like this:

```js
switch (product.category){
          case 'entree':
              this.entreeAll.push(product);
              break
          case 'plat':
              this.platAll.push(product);
              break
          case 'dessert':
              this.dessertAll.push(product);
              break
          case 'boisson':
              this.boissonAll.push(product);
              break
          case 'accompagnement':
              this.accompagnementAll.push(product);
              break
          case 'supplement':
              this.supplementAll.push(product);
              break
      }
```

One other doing the same switch case :

```js
switch (category){
        case 'entree':
            this.waitEntree = value;
            break
        case 'plat':
            this.waitPlat = value;
            break
        case 'dessert':
            this.waitDessert = value;
            break
        case 'boisson':
            this.waitBoisson = value;
            break
        case 'accompagnement':
            this.waitAccompagnement= value;
            break
        case 'supplement':
            this.waitSupplement = value;
            break
    }
```

So, i answered myself and say maybe go create a Switcher function. But if i doing that i need to pass in parameters my category and what i need to do.

```js
switcher(category, useful){
      switch (category){
          case 'entree':
              if(useful === 'update'){
                  this.waitEntree = value;
              }else if(useful === 'created'){
                  this.entreeAll.push(product);

              }else {
                  this.waitEntree.slice(0,1);
              }
              break
          case 'plat': ...............................
```

But for me i think is not a good way, if someone can lighting me how is the good way for doing that!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the names are pretty same, you should be able to dynamically access the variables with very few lines of code like so.

```js
this[`${product.category}All`].push()
this[`${product.category}Wait`] = value
```

That should be all that you need, if you think these may not exist in some cases then you can just do a quick check before running them so you don't run into an error like so.

```js
function addProduct(productList, category) {
  const productArray = productList[`${category}All`];
  if (Array.isArray(productArray))) { 
     return productArray.push();
  } 

  return false;
}

addProduct(this, category);
```

Comment: I search a long time and i thinks is isn't possible to have a this variable dynamic !

So i can do what i want at very first time and replace all of this by two code line, thanks you !

update(value, category){
            this[`wait${product.category}`] = product;

        },

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, more often than not a switch case is a good indicator that you can simplify your code especially when there are obvious patterns that exist in your switch cases.

Since your method names are very similar to the category names, I would just rebuild the method name.

Here is a working example, where you have two methods createProduct and updateProduct. You could of course combine the two into one single function but sometimes it's nice *not* to mix update and creates.

```js
function createProduct(product) {
  try {
    this[`${product.category}All`].push(product);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    // catch the error if the method doesn't exist
    // think of this as the defautl for the switch
    console.warn(`Category ${product.category}  does not exist`);
    return false;
  }
}

function updateProduct(product, value) {
  const {
    category
  } = product;
  const key = 'wait' + category[0].toUpperCase() + category.slice(1);
  if (this[key] !== undefined) {
    this[key] = value;
    return true;
  } else {
    console.warn(`Category ${product.category} does not exist`);
    return false;
  }

}

// creating mock variables
window.entreeAll = [];
window.waitEntree = {};

createProduct({
  category: 'entree'
});
console.log(entreeAll);
updateProduct({
  category: 'entree'
}, 'hello world');
console.log(waitEntree);
createProduct({
  category: 'doesnotexist'
});
```

Comment: for `updateProduct` function, this will not fail as expected, `this[\`wait${key}\`] = value` will silently create a new entry into `this` and not throw any error, in this case the better approach is to check if `this[\`wait${key}\`]` exists first

Comment: Welcome, also I would like to point out for the OP that this in the context of the function may not point to the this referred in the switch code. So when they invoke it they may need to call it after switching context `createProduct.call(this, { category: 'entree' })` alternatively, can pass in "this" as an argument to be manipulated as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I should probably do something with a switcher functions but (for me) more readable :

```
function switcher(category, useful = "update") {
  switch (true) {
    case category == "entree" && useful === "update":
      this.waitEntree = value;
      break;
    case category == "entree" && useful === "created":
      this.entreeAll.push(product);
      break;
    [......]
  }
}
```

But i'm not sure it's the best idea to mix create and update, depends of your project